# Javaのバージョンを1.6から1.8に変えたい

Tags: java, macos, eclipse

Eclipseを使用するために、macにあるJavaのバージョンを1.6から1.8に変更したいのですが、Javaのバージョンをアップデートしてもmacに反映されません。
Javaのコントールパネルには`プラット1.8`と表示されているのですが、ターミナルで`Java -version`で検索をかけると`java version "1.6.0_65"`となっています。
`java runtime environment設定`のパスには`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`と表示されていました。

Comment: 「java mac 複数」でググれば、たくさん解説記事が出てきますよ

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べて試してみます

Comment: (少なくともApple/OracleのサイトからダウンロードしたJDKだと)通常では、インストールされている中で最も新しいバージョンのjavaが利用されます。`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`(Vは大文字)でインストールされているjavaバージョンの一覧が取得できますが、想定通りのバージョンがインストールされているでしょうか。あるいは、ターミナル上では、`JAVA_HOME`環境変数が設定されているとそちらのバージョンが優先して使用されます。`echo $JAVA_HOME`コマンド実行で何か出力されるでしょうか。(さらに言うと、ターミナルが利用するjava = Eclipseが利用するjava、というわけでも無いのです。Eclispeで利用できるようになっているかどうかはEclipse上で確認するのが確実です。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse で Java1.8環境が利用できるかどうかは [Execution Environments](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments) (Preferences の  Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments)で **JavaSE-1.8** の欄を見てみてください。 **Compatible JREs** にインストールしたJavaの情報が出ていれば利用可能です。
質問文にかかれている情報を見る限り、1.8のインストールは正常に完了していると思われます。その場合、Eclipse上でも自動で認識されているはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

> ターミナルでJava -versionで検索をかけるとjava version "1.6.0_65"となっています。

これについては、おそらく `~/.bash_profile` (など)で 環境変数`JAVA_HOME`を設定しており、その向き先が1.6になっているからだと思われます。

ターミナルで利用するJavaのバージョンを1.8に変更する場合は、その`JAVA_HOME`設定を更新してください。